# How to display popup in android same as Android market used?

Tags: android, popupwindow

If any have clue of this popup. so please share with us.

See this below image. I want like that way...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean the error field as in:

```
editTextPhoneNumber.setError("Invalid Phone #");
```

You can also use hints on success as in:

```
editTextPhoneNumber.setHint("Success Sending SMS");
```

Have fun,
JAL